# Where to change default pdf page width and font size in jspdf.debug.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jspdf

I need to **change default pdf page width and font size** in jspdf.debug.js.

Where and how to change the default values in jspdf.debug.js?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Besides using one of the default formats you can specify any size you want in the unit you specify.

For example:

```
// Document of 210mm wide and 297mm high
new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [297, 210]);
// Document of 297mm wide and 210mm high
new jsPDF('l', 'mm', [297, 210]);
// Document of 5 inch width and 3 inch high
new jsPDF('l', 'in', [3, 5]);
```

The 3rd parameter of the constructor can take an array of the dimensions. However they do not correspond to width and height, instead they are long side and short side (or flipped around).

Your 1st parameter (`landscape` or `portrait`) determines what becomes the width and the height.

In the sourcecode on GitHub you can see the [supported units (relative proportions to `pt`)](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/ddbfc0f0250ca908f8061a72fa057116b7613e78/jspdf.js#L791), and you can also see the default [page formats (with their sizes in `pt`)](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/ddbfc0f0250ca908f8061a72fa057116b7613e78/jspdf.js#L59).

Comment: if i want to change the length of one page only is this possible

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it's not possible (maybe there's a plugin for this), but skimming through the source code made it seem pretty clear it's not in the default implementation.

Comment: Could you look at this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25001939/not-getting-desired-output-in-jspdf)

Comment: Yes, you can. Check my answer on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41848540/jspdf-change-page-format/46504177#46504177

Comment: Neat, but back in the day, `addPage` did not yet take arguments: [old](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/ddbfc0f0250ca908f8061a72fa057116b7613e78/jspdf.js#L612), [new](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/jspdf.js#L762).

Comment: Think your solution is related with this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104008/where-to-change-default-pdf-page-width-and-font-size-in-jspdf-debug-js

Answer (score 40):

From the [documentation page](http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/doc/symbols/jsPDF.html)

To set the page type pass the value in constructor

> `jsPDF(orientation, unit, format)` Creates new jsPDF document object
>
> instance Parameters:
>
> **orientation** One of "portrait" or "landscape" (or shortcuts "p" (Default), "l")
>
> **unit** Measurement unit to be used when  coordinates are specified. One of "pt" (points), "mm" (Default), "cm", "in"
>
> **format** One of 'a3', 'a4' (Default),'a5' ,'letter' ,'legal'

To set font size

> `setFontSize(size)`
>
> Sets font size for upcoming text elements.
>
> Parameters:
>
> {Number} size Font size in points.

Answer (score 17):

My case was to print horizontal (landscape) summary section - so:

```
}).then((canvas) => {
  const img = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');
  new jsPDF({
        orientation: 'l', // landscape
        unit: 'pt', // points, pixels won't work properly
        format: [canvas.width, canvas.height] // set needed dimensions for any element
  });
  pdf.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  pdf.save('your-filename.pdf');
});
```

Comment: The tip with unit: 'pt' Helped get me closer.

Comment: @Kurkov You sir are a total genius!

Comment: Orientation was the thing that helped me. Even if we declare width and height in array in reverse order, and if orientation is still portrait it takes larger parameter as height always.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone trying to this in react. There is a slight difference.

```
// Document of 8.5 inch width and 11 inch high
new jsPDF('p', 'in', [612, 792]);
```

or

```
// Document of 8.5 inch width and 11 inch high
new jsPDF({
        orientation: 'p', 
        unit: 'in', 
        format: [612, 792]
});
```

When i tried the @Aidiakapi solution the pages were tiny.  For a difference size take size in inches * 72 to get the dimensions you need. For example, i wanted 8.5 so 8.5 * 72 = 612.
This is for jspdf@1.5.3.