# Not getting desired output in jspdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jspdf

```
CODE:


//This html is store in a div of someclass
<a>"i"
"f you think the perfect yo clone has not been build then there is ...."
```

i got the output like this!![image]

and my main code is here

```
var question_main  = document.getElementsByClassName("someclass");
question = $(question_main).html();
 var specialElementHandlers_main = {
                 '#test': function(element, renderer){
                  return true;
                                }
                                   };

      doc.fromHTML(question, 15, length, {
               'width': 175, 
               'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers_main

                                  });
```

What wrong in that why i am getting some othere values(by) in py pdf? How to solve it?
Is there any way so  that i can remove the gap between **"i"** nd **"f you..**.I think they are creating some problems?

Comment: Can you make a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/) or [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that exactly demonstrates the issue? It is currently not really clear what your code is, and why it's not working.

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sompathak/MPmLd/4/) as you can see that the text is somewhat destroted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because jspdf does not support UTF-8 characters `don’t to don't`